# How can I get the remote machine with Windows Server 2008 after “route /f” executed on it?

Tags: windows-server-2008, route

Here is the thing, I had made a stupid mistake yesterday. I run "route /f" on a remote machine with Windows Server 2008, and this command cleared the routing tables, including the default route, which is fatal.

Since no one is working on the remote side now, I could not restart the machine. This stupid mistake makes me could not reach the machine thought remote desktop, I have tried to access the machine on another machine (in the same LAN with the broken remote machine), but it did not work.

Is there any way I can get the default route back, so that I could access the remote machine by remote desktop again? Any advice is appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: +1 - Interesting situation. If you were on the same LAN segment, it should not have mattered if there was no default route... there must be something larger going on...

Comment: @Mark Henderson I tried to ping the broken machine, and I got the arp cache updated with the valid physical address, so I think the machine is still alive

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/352712/how-to-remotely-reboot-a-hung-server

Answer (score 0):

In general, even without the default route the host is still able to communicate within its own broadcast domain. If the Windows Firewall is up, it is quite likely ICMP echoes are filtered, so you would not get responses to ping.

Just try RDP'ing in from the same network. If it fails for some reason (filtered, broken, whatever), check if you still can access the machine via SMB like typing `\\server` or `\\192.168.0.12` (exchange for your server's IP address) into the Explorer address bar. If this turns out to work, try either using [`psexec \\server cmd` (psexec is an optional download)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) for establishing a remote shell for further debugging or getting to schedule a task remotely which would run a batch for the same purpose.

Comment: This doesn't work, look like "route /f" also delete the broadcast route.